# Sequence of harmonic-mean of a convergent-sequence converges to the same limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $(a_n) \rightarrow a$.

Then $$H_n:= \frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}$$ converges to $a.$

---

I went through the brute force method: $|H_n-a| < \epsilon$.

Since $(a_n)\to a$ and if $a\neq0$ then $(\frac{1}{a_n}) \to \frac1 a$ and for sufficiently large $n$, all $\frac{1}{a_n}$ can be replaced by $\frac1 a$.

I observed that $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}}=a$.

Now how to convert this idea into a rigorous proof?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please provide me with some hint. I thought of some ways but none are going in a good direction.

Comment: Please show your ways and what you have tried.

Comment: Firstly I went through brute force method. $|H_n-a| < \epsilon.$ Since $(a_n) \rightarrow a$. So $(1/a_n) \rightarrow 1/a.$ So for sufficiently large n, all $1/a_n$ can be replaced by $1/a$.

I observed that $\frac{n}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a}+...+\frac{1}{a}}=a$. Now how to convert this idea into a rigorous proof?

Comment: Yuo should include this description into your question.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and including it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler way is by [Stolz–Cesàro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)

$$ \frac{(n+1)-n}{\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+...+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)}$$

As an alternative we can consider the reciprocal $\frac1{H_n}$ and use this result

- [Limit of the arithmetic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2517716/505767)

Comment: Can we not prove this result without using the result mentioned above?